# WPF DataContext returns null when referrencing another ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf

i basically open a `InformationWindow.xaml` through a control in my `ReportGenerator.xaml`.
In the code behind `InformationWindow.xaml.cs` i want to access a public string from the `ReportGeneratorViewModel.cs`.

I tried with DataContext in the `InformationWindow.xaml.cs` as it normaly works:

```
var Context = (ReportGeneratorViewModel)DataContext;
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Context.rootfolder + "\\Userinfo", "Benutzer*.*");
```

But this always returns "null" for Context. What is the problem here?

Comment: You have to set the DataContext somewhere; either in XAML or in CodeBedind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `DataContext` of the window before you open it:

```
InformationWindow informationWindow = new InformationWindow() { DataContext = this.DataContext };
informationWindow.Show();
```